# Задать фикстуры для тестов

Tags: php, yii2, тестирование, codeception

Не нахожу в доках как задавать фикстуры для тестов. Т.е. некие тестовые данные для каждой таблицы. Думаю идеально было бы даже иметь отдельную тестовую базу данных, но мне бы хотелось чтобы она заполнялась при старте тестов и очищалась в конце. Чтобы если что-то изменил в ней тестами - то при перезапуске тестов все было как новое. Вот например в корне тестов есть папка _data, кажется в нее надо пихать фикстуры? Но в каком формате? И как их подцепить потом? Хотелось бы конечно простым массивом или в json указывать, чтобы просто было менять при необходимости. Все равно данных не много надо для тестов.

И еще вопрос меня очень волнует: как вообще выполнять что-то до и после всех тестов (в пределах одного файла хотя бы)? У тестов есть методы _before и _after, но они выполняются до и после каждого тестового метода, а мне нужно до и после всех тестовых методов (хотя-бы в пределах одного тестового класса). Например те же самые фикстуры нет смысла заливать и очищать перед/после каждого метода и еще бывают разные задачи.

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/test-fixtures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фикстуры (англ. fixtures) - это важная составляющая тестирования. Их основная задача заключается в подготовке окружения с заранее фиксированным/известным состоянием для гарантии повторяемости процесса тестирования. Yii предоставляет фреймворк, который позволяет легко и точно определять фикстуры и использовать их в ваших тестах.

Ключевым понятием в фреймворке фикстур Yii является так называемый объект фикстуры. Объект фикстуры представляет собой особый аспект тестового окружения, который наследуется от yii\test\Fixture или его наследников. Например, вы можете использовать UserFixture для того, чтобы быть уверенным, что таблица пользователей содержит известный набор данных. Вы загружаете один или несколько объектов фикстур перед запуском теста и выгружаете их после его завершения.

Фикстура может зависеть от других фикстур, заданных через свойство yii\test\Fixture::$depends. Когда фикстура загружается, фикстуры от которых она зависит будут автоматически загружены ДО нее, а когда она выгружается все зависимые фикстуры будут выгружены ПОСЛЕ нее.
(https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/test-fixtures)